# Optimizing Oracle Procedure for Efficiently Processing Large Tables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am working on a Oracle stored procedure which loops through every record of the table & perform calculations & save the result of that calculation on the same record in "Results" field. This table has around 15-20 million records.

I need a way to track the processing status of records, the number of records remaining, and implement incremental commits to resume processing from the last commit point in case of a failure.

Currently, I don't know how many records are processed or whether or not this procedure is going to complete. Also, if there is any unhandled exception occurs it shouldn't start processing from record #1.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement for your procedure; a complete English (not code) explanation of the logic that you want to implement; details of the issues/errors with your current procedure; and the expected output for that sample data. We **CANNOT** help you if you do not share any code.

Comment: @MT0 Thank you for downvote. I am only looking for design approach for my problem. Actual table & the complex mathematical transaction I am performing on each record is irrelevant here. My current procedure is thousands of lines long but right now I only care about how to get information on number of records it has processed & not having to re-start the processing in case of error.

Comment: The whole point of asking for a [MRE] is that it is **minimal**. I did not ask for your actual tables, data or procedures; I asked for something that was representative of the problem and **minimal**.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, switch to set-oriented processing, i.e. update the whole table *at once*. Though, that might cause problems (hint: rollback segment size) as millions of rows are involved. Also, if processing is complex, that might not even fit into a single `update` statement.

If it has to be row-by-row, then - for easier logging purposes - create an autonomous transaction procedure which would log rows which have already been processed into another table. Doing so, you could always query it and see what's already been done. Don't rely on DBMS_OUTPUT because it won't *print* anything until the whole procedure is over, and - then - it is too late as you'll already know the outcome.

Include inner BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END block into the loop. Exception handling section should log errors (into appropriate table) and would NOT raise error, but let the next loop round to continue processing.

As of committing, create a local variable which is incremented in a loop; check its value and once it reaches e.g. 100.000 commit and reset it. Commit at the end of the procedure as well.

Simplified:

```
declare
  i number := 0;
begin
  for cur_r in (select id from some_table) loop
    begin
      update target table set ...
      i := i + 1;
      if i = 100000 then
         commit;
         i := 0;
      end if;
      p_log(cur_r.id);             -- mark this ID as "processed"

    exception
      when others then
        p_err(cur_r.id, sqlerrm);  -- store ID and error message
    end;
  end loop;
  commit;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was leaning towards the similar approach of keeping an external table to keep track of number of rows that are processed & committing the results after N number of records periodically. Yes, calculations are complex enough involving fetching data from different tables, summarize them, fill the details in formula & do execute immediate to get final results.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to "update" every row in the table, you are going to be better off just re-creating the table, with the calculated data.

```
insert into new_tab
select old_tab_columns..., <results_calc>
from old_tab
```

You can then take advantage of parallel processing, direct path load, nologging, etc

Comment: Right now, this doesn't seem to be an option for me as the process of calculating results itself is very complex. I am heavily using cursors in this process, including 5 inner cursors, which navigate different parts of the formula to calculate the final results. If there are any general rules to follow when using cursors or loops in Oracle, I would like to hear them.